# Preventing or getting rid of encoded response data from ajax call

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to retrieve an image via an ajax call and while the json value returned holds the right value (e.g no `%20` in the image path), jQuery is encoding the response data. I've looked around this site and others but have had no luck in finding anything that helps me fix this issue. Here is the response I am getting

json -

```
item_image: "/public/images/uploads/store/3/Jimmy's Store/Computers/items/computers_PC 111_test_image_adding_1.jpg"
```

which again, is what I want but this is what jQuery is doing (I know the data is encoded, I just don't know how to get it to where the returned value is not encoded):

```
GET http://localhost/public/images/uploads/store/3/Jimmy's%20Store/Computers/items/computers_PC%20111_test_image_adding_1.jpg
```

Basically I am trying to keep the whitespace intact and not having it encoded. I don't know if there is a way to do this but any help would be appreciated.

I've tried `decodeURIComponent` but that doesn't seem to do anything..

Thanks!

Comment: That is proper url encoding. You shouldn't be allowing spaces in directories, or apostrophes

Comment: I know that but I'm using PHP to actually format the directories to allow for it. I'm just trying to get the value without the encoding.

Comment: well...go against standards and you run into problems like this

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice and took out the formatting and removed the whitespace, and it works. Thanks for the advice, I should have done it from the beginning.